# Optimise slow code - enumeration of dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios

I have the following code that decodes a JSON string into an array of objects that I can then use in a UITableView.

At first I thought the JSON decoding was the slow part but it appears that it is not as the "Dictionary Done" appears almost immediately.

Any ideas on how to get that code to be a little faster?

```
-(void)parseJSON:(NSString *)jsonData{

    NSLog(@"Start parsing");
    NSDictionary *deserializedData = [jsonData objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary Done");

    NSArray *flights = [deserializedData valueForKeyPath:@"flights.flight"];
    NSMutableArray *localArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
    NSString *lastFlightno =@"";

    for (NSDictionary *flight in flights){

        ArchiveFlight *aFlight = [[ArchiveFlight alloc] initWithFlightno:[flight objectForKey:@"flightno"] route:[flight objectForKey:@"route"]];
        aFlight.flightID = [flight objectForKey:@"primary_key"];
        aFlight.timeStamp = [aFlight niceDate:[flight objectForKey:@"timestamp"]];

        if (![lastFlightno isEqualToString:aFlight.flightno]) {
            [localArray addObject:aFlight];
        }

        lastFlightno =aFlight.flightno;
        [aFlight release];
    }
    NSLog(@"End Parsing");
    [self loadupTable:localArray];
    self.flightArray = localArray;
    [localArray release];

}
```

EDIT: Added timestamps

Timestamps of the NSLogs as follows...

```
2011-04-26 13:22:36.104 App[1778:707] Finished request
2011-04-26 13:22:36.109 App[1778:707] Start parsing
2011-04-26 13:22:36.128 App[1778:707] Dictionary Done
2011-04-26 13:22:37.713 App[1778:707] End Parsing
```

Sample of the JSON...

```
{"flights":[{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR54WP","timestamp":"2011-04-26 12:13:04","route":"EGNX-LEAL","primary_key":"836453"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR24LU","timestamp":"2011-04-26 09:14:03","route":"EVRA-EGNX","primary_key":"831318"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR39WH","timestamp":"2011-04-26 05:33:03","route":"EGNX-EVRA","primary_key":"825492"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR7PX","timestamp":"2011-04-25 20:07:03","route":"LELC-EGNX","primary_key":"816703"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR2VB","timestamp":"2011-04-25 16:57:06","route":"EGNX-LELC","primary_key":"810900"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR3JN","timestamp":"2011-04-25 12:36:04","route":"GCTS-EGNX","primary_key":"802631"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR8GV","timestamp":"2011-04-25 06:07:03","route":"EGNX-GCTS","primary_key":"792945"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR82QR","timestamp":"2011-04-24 19:42:04","route":"EPKK-EGNX","primary_key":"783306"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR51PV","timestamp":"2011-04-24 16:31:05","route":"EGNX-EPKK","primary_key":"777835"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR53AQ","timestamp":"2011-04-24 14:09:05","route":"LIME-EGNX","primary_key":"773572"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR1CX","timestamp":"2011-04-24 11:02:05","route":"EGNX-LIME","primary_key":"768285"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR9ZW","timestamp":"2011-04-24 08:21:04","route":"LEGE-EGNX","primary_key":"764624"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR63BC","timestamp":"2011-04-24 05:48:02","route":"EGNX-LEGE","primary_key":"761726"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"RYR7PX","timestamp":"2011-04-23 19:39:03"
```

Formatted sample:

```
{
   "flights":[
      {
         "flight":{
            "flightno":"RYR54WP",
            "timestamp":"2011-04-26 12:13:04",
            "route":"EGNX-LEAL",
            "primary_key":"836453"
         }
      },
      {
         "flight":{
            "flightno":"RYR24LU",
            "timestamp":"2011-04-26 09:14:03",
            "route":"EVRA-EGNX",
            "primary_key":"831318"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

So here is "niceDate" that is causing the slowdown!

```
-(NSString *)niceDate:(NSString *)oldDate{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *sourceDate = [formatter dateFromString:oldDate];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeString];
}
```

Comment: Have you put in some profiling timestamps to see which part is taking up the most time?

Comment: Added some timestamps, but can't really insert some within the loop without that really then slowing down!

Comment: Of how many iterations are we talking? You could put in some logging code and just see how your loop peforms for the first 10/50/100 iterations. Maybe performance is degrading because of something?

Comment: Oh certainly, there is 1000 rows and the only bit that increases in time is the bit inside the Fast Enumeration

Comment: What's the time after `NSArray *flights = [deserializedData valueForKeyPath:@"flights.flight"];`, it's not within the loop, so is this time consuming?

Comment: @Nick’s is a good point. Also, you might want to feed more data and profile your application via Instruments — it should give you a better picture of the performance behaviour in that code.

Comment: That part take .001 of a second, so pretty quick!

Comment: @Lee The next step would be to show your `-niceDate:` method.

Comment: @Lee Armstrong, ok can you add timestamp in your loop to get a detailed picture how long every part takes? Just for one iteration. From the console log 1k flights take up ~1.6 seconds to parse.

Comment: It was the niceDate!  Taking that bit out makes it parse in .01 second.  Will add that method to the question.

Comment: Question is: do you need the nicedate in the parsing? Isn't it possible to move it to the view part?

Comment: Hmmm, well it is in a UITableview so I suppose I could but that may be a little trickier!

Comment: Show us the code how you setup the cell, shouldn't be a problem ;)

Comment: Ah, well I am using Sensible Table View for this one, I am tempted to rewrite it because of this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things that come to mind:

```
NSArray *flights = [deserializedData valueForKeyPath:@"flights.flight"];
```

Do you need to use KVC? What is the structure of your JSON data?

```
ArchiveFlight *aFlight = [[ArchiveFlight alloc] initWithFlightno:[flight objectForKey:@"flightno"] route:[flight objectForKey:@"route"]];
aFlight.flightID = [flight objectForKey:@"primary_key"];
aFlight.timeStamp = [aFlight niceDate:[flight objectForKey:@"timestamp"]];
```

You always create an instance of `ArchiveFlight` and parse the timestamp…

```
    if (![lastFlightno isEqualToString:aFlight.flightno]) {
        [localArray addObject:aFlight];
    }
```

…even though you don’t have to do that all the time. Depending on how many repeated `flightnos` you have, this can make a noticeable difference.

Why not read `[flight objectForKey:@"flightno"]`, compare it to `lastFlightno` and, if and only if they’re different, create an instance, add it to the array, and release it?

---

**Edit:** Try the following KVC-free code:

```
NSArray *flights = [deserializedData objectForKey:@"flights"];
NSMutableArray *localArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
NSString *lastFlightno =@"";

for (NSDictionary *flightWrapper in flights) {
    NSDictionary *flight = [flightWrapper objectForKey:@"flight"];
    NSString *flightno = [flight objectForKey:@"flightno"];

    if (! [flightno isEqual:lastFlightno]) {
        // create instance, add it to the array, release the instance
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** You’re creating and (auto)releasing two instances of `NSDateFormatter` inside this method. In general this would be okay, but since it is being executed >1K times there are two considerations: a) you’re creating/using/releasing those two instances >1K times when, in fact, you don’t have two, b) you should use an autorelease pool in your loop.

You should make this method a class method (or a function) since it doesn’t depend on the state of an instance of that class. Your formatters would be class (static) variables. For instance:

```
@implementation ArchiveFlight

static NSDateFormatter *formatter1; // choose better names!
static NSDateFormatter *formatter2;

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [ArchiveFlight class]) {
        formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter2 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        [formatter2 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    }
}

+ (NSString *)niceDate:(NSString *)oldDate {
    NSDate *sourceDate = [formatter1 dateFromString:oldDate];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter2 stringFromDate:sourceDate];
    return timeString;
    // why +stringWithFormat:? It’s not necessary!
    // return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeString];
}
```

This fixes item a) but you really should use an autorelease pool inside your loop because the Cocoa methods you’re using return autoreleased objects. By using an autorelease pool for each iteration of your loop, you reduce the memory footprint of your code — although this *could* decrease performance as well. I suggest you try both with and without an inner autorelease pool.

```
for (NSDictionary *flightWrapper in flights) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    …

    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added a sample of the JSON to the original question....there are not many repeated flightno's but a good simple fix indeed there that will shave a little bit off!

I think the bulk of it is on the KVC, is there another way?

Comment: Thanks, that is a little quicker.  1.2 seconds now to do the loop statements though.  Still a little bit too long and can't understand why when the request over the network and JSONKit doing it all VERY quick!  Confusing!

Comment: See above, it is the niceDate function doing it....now to get to the bottom of that! :-(

Comment: If the code is still a bit slow, I would guess the ArchiveFlight object is "expensive" to create, perhaps you should look if you can optimize this object in any way.

Comment: @Lee And again! I’ve removed `+stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: I've moved to another place and only got the one formatter and it now flies!  Thanks!